# implementing an abstract base class function in another template base class

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project where I have a class that inherits from an abstract base class and another template class that implements a function in the abstract base class. For example:

```
class Foo;

struct Buzz
{
    virtual ~Buzz() {};
    virtual void Buzz_Do( Foo* ) = 0;
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};
    virtual void Base_Do( Buzz* ) = 0;
};

template< class T >
class Bar
{
public:
    virtual void Base_Do( Buzz* v )
    {
        v->Buzz_Do( static_cast< T* >( this ) );
    };
};

class Foo : public Base, public Bar< Foo >
{
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo c;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this yields the compiler error:

```
1>MyApp.cpp(39) : error C2259: 'Foo' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>        due to following members:
1>        'void Base::Base_Do(Buzz *)' : is abstract
1>        MyApp.cpp(17) : see declaration of 'Base::Base_Do'
```

I've tried adding a public `using Bar< Foo >::Base_Do;` to `class Foo`, but that did not help.

Is there a way to make this work or will I need to put a concrete `Base_Do()` implementation in `Foo` and not use `Bar<>`?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: Just to clarify the terminology: a class that has a pure virtual function is called an *abstract class* in C++, not a "virtual base class".

Comment: -1 Incorrect assertions, invalid code. This is not your actual code and if your assertions bear any semblance to reality, then the presented code does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible let the `Bar<>` derive from Base,
and Foo derive only from `Bar<T>`.

Comment: And please, please, please, do no try virtual inheritance. Amok's solution is really the way you should go.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the compiler can tell, your template function *doesn't* actually implement the function from the base class. The compiler thinks that `Base::Base_Do` and `Bar<T>::Base_Do` are two completely unrelated functions, NOT an implementation of one.

What the compiler sees is that `Foo` winds up with two functions of (almost) the same name: `Base::Base_Do` and `Bar<T>::Base_Do`. Bar doesn't implement `Base`'s interface at all.

I think what you really want is for `Bar<T>` to inherit from `Base` and implement `Base_Do`. Then have `Foo` inherit just from `Bar<Foo>`.

But even with all that, can you tell us more clearly what problem *you're actually trying to solve*? Then we can offer advice on how to solve that. The relationship between `Buzz` and `Foo`, and `Foo` to `Bar` and `Base` confuses me.

EDIT:
Also see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.10 as that might offer an alternative mechanism that still allows you to use the mixin.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to cause a function defined in one base to override a function by the same name in another base when those bases are unrelated.  It doesn't work that way.  You either have to have your template base inherit from the abstract base, or write the function in your derived class to call the function in your non-abstract base.

Which you do depends greatly upon your problem.  I generally prefer the former but have run into situations where it is not possible (because the bases I need are simply not related) and use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
template< class T , class K>

class Bar: public K
{
public:
    virtual void Base_Do( Buzz* v )
    {
        v->Buzz_Do( static_cast< T* >( this ) );
    };
};

class Foo : public Bar< Foo, Base >
{
};
```

`Foo` deriver from `Base`, which has undefined virtual method. You could make it like I wrote or make derivation `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Foo extends Base, before instantiating Foo (`Foo c;`), you need to implement all virtual methods of Base. In your example, you need to implement `virtual void Base_Do( Buzz* )`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error:

```
> 1>MyApp.cpp(39) : error C2259: 'Foo' :
> cannot instantiate abstract class 1>  
> due to following members: 1>       
> 'void Base::Base_Do(Buzz *)' : is
> abstract 1>        MyApp.cpp(17) : see
> declaration of 'Base::Base_Do'
```

Foo is an abstract class. You cannot create instance of it. First implements all the virtual functions it inherits from the base classes.

Comment: For your last question, this is perfectly legal and called the "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern", or CRTP in short.

Comment: @Alexandre. yeah. I just noticed that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++
>   project where I have a class that
>   inherits from a virtual base class and
>   another template class that implements
>   a function in the virtual base class.

- Wrong: Your code has no virtual base classes.

Here is your code (as I'm writing this):

```
class Foo;

struct Buzz
{
    virtual ~Buzz() {};
    virtual void Buzz_Do( Foo* ) = 0;
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};
    virtual void Base_Do( Buzz* ) = 0;
};

template< class T >
class Bar
{
public:
    virtual void Base_Do( Buzz* v )
    {
        v->Buzz_Do( static_cast< T* >( this ) );
    };
};

class Foo : public Base, public Bar< Foo >
{
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo c;
    return 0;
}
```

Further,

- Wrong: The pure virtual member function `Buzz_Do` is not implemented anywhere.
- Wrong: Your code lacks a `main` function (although readers could supply one, I guess).
- Wrong: The macro (or type) `_TCHAR` is nowhere defined.

Having said that, virtual inheritance – which you claim that your *actual code* is using – is one possible answer to the question that it seems you intended to ask.

However, with your invalid presented code and incorrect assertions about that code, not much can reasonably be said. I note that others have tried anyway. Perhaps, if you're lucky, one of those answers will fit the bill, but it's just a game of chance.

Cheers & hth.,