# c++ abstract class implementation in another base class

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

**Question**

Why not to try virtual inheritance if it seems to solve my diamond inheritance problem below?

**Briefing:**

While learning C++, I came with some compiler errors for the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

class IFoo{
    public:
    virtual void Hello() = 0;
};

class Foo : public IFoo{
    public:
    void Hello()
    {
        printf("Hello");
    }
};

class IBar : public IFoo{
    public:
    virtual void HelloWorld() = 0;
};

class Bar : public IBar, public Foo{
    public:
    void HelloWorld()
    {
        Hello();
        printf("World");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    b.HelloWorld();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I want Bar to implement abstract class IBar which has IFoo as a base class but then I want all the implementation of IFoo provided by Bar's second base class Foo.

I get 2 compiler errors (GCC 4.9.2): One related to ambiguities and another one about missing implementations for abstract class IFoo.

Then I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441797/implementing-an-abstract-base-class-function-in-another-template-base-class) and got to meet the concept of virtual inheritance, which lead me to [this page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html). Following the tutorial, I added virtual inheritance and all problems were gone:

```
class Foo : public virtual IFoo{...
class IBar : public virtual IFoo{...
```

But a user in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441797/implementing-an-abstract-base-class-function-in-another-template-base-class) suggest not to try virtual inheritance. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Hello()` call in `Bar::HelloWorld()` is ambiguous. The compiler can't tell if you are trying to call `Hello()` from `IBar` or `Foo`.  You can call `Foo::Hello()` or `IBar::Hello()` in it's place.  That being said, your inheritance structure doesn't really make sense.

Your `Bar` class also needs to override `Hello` that it inherits from `IBar`.

If you have c++11, it would be a good idea to mark the virtual functions you are overriding with the `override` keyword:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

class IFoo{
    public:
    virtual void Hello() = 0;
};

class Foo : public IFoo{
    public:
    virtual void Hello() override
    {
        printf("Hello");
    }
};

class IBar : public IFoo{
    public:
    virtual void HelloWorld() = 0;
};

class Bar : public IBar, public Foo{
    public:
    virtual void HelloWorld() override
    {
        Foo::Hello();
        printf("World");
    }

     void Hello() override {}
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    b.HelloWorld();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

To answer your question on virtual inheritance, you could easily change your inheritance structure to something that still works that avoids a diamond pattern.  The diamond pattern is rarely needed and is usually avoidable:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

class IFoo{
public:
    virtual void Hello() = 0;
};

class Foo : public IFoo{
public:
    virtual void Hello() override
    {
        printf("Hello");
    }
};

class IBar {
public:
    virtual void World() = 0;
};

class Bar : public IBar{
public:
    virtual void World() override
    {
        printf("World");
    }
};

class FooBar : public Foo, public Bar
{
public:
    virtual void HelloWorld()
    {
        Hello();
        World();
    }
};

int main()
{
    FooBar b;
    b.HelloWorld();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right. I tried Foo::Hello() in Bar::HelloWorld() without virtual inheritance and got rid of ambiguity. I'm also learning with C++11 so I'll adopt the override practice. This inheritance structure may not make sense now but if IFoo has 1000+ function definitions then it would be really tedious to override all of them in Bar with functions of the form Bar::func1000() override { Foo::func1000(); }. That's why I was expecting Foo to provide the implementation but this only works with virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Heinz The question is, why are you having bar inherit from both `Foo` and `IBar`?  You end up inheriting from `Foo` twice, which is what is causing your problems.  
The need of virtual inheritance more often than not implies poor design.  There are definitely uses for it, but here it doesn't make sense.  
Also, if your question has been answered you should mark one of the answers as accepted.

Comment: @Heinz [Check this out](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your class

```
Bar
```

must override

```
Hello
```

otherwise class Bar also becomes purely abstract, because

```
Hello
```

is inherited all the way from

```
IFoo.
```

Whenever a class inherits an abtract base class it must implement all of the base class' pure virtual functions, otherwise the derived class itself also becomes abstract.

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

// this class is abstract, it doesn't implement Base::foo
class Derived1 : public Base{
public:
    void fooDerived() {}
};

// this class is not abstract, it implements Base::foo
class Derived2 : public Base{
public:
    void foo() {}
};
```

As suggested in another answer, in C++11 you can declare the function using the override keyword, which ensures that the function overrides a **virtual** function. Like this:

```
   // this class is not abstract, it implements Base::foo
class Derived2 : public Base{
public:
    void foo() override {}
};
```

**Virtual inheritance** solves another problem, the problem of ambiguity when inheriting from more than one base class which declares identical functions or members.

Comment: In this case I can override Hello() in Bar easily with Bar::Hello() override { Foo::Hello(); } to give it at least some functionality but imagine doing this for every function IFoo might have in future (1000+ to be exaggerated), I'll have to maintain IFoo, Foo and now Bar...virtual inheritance helped solving that by using Foo's implementation but still don't know why it is suggested not to use it.

Comment: If you're having problems maintaining the inheritance structure between IFoo, Foo and Bar that's a design problem. Virtual functions and abstract base classes do serve a valid purpose in object-oriented programming. I would state absolutes such as "don't use virtual inheritance".

Comment: I think it is more of a lazyness problem :) but sure, I have no major issues applying a design without virtual inheritance by overriding Hello in Bar and calling Foo::Hello() in Bar::HelloWorld(), if it must be done then let's do it, this seems to work just fine.
I just wan't to know why virtual inheritance is not a better choise, Does it have a performance penalty for example?